# Access Webpack DevServer from a Webpack plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

Is it possible to somehow access the DevServer instance from a Webpack plugin? I would like to send a custom event from the server to the client (e.g. after a specific file change).

I saw that this is totally [possible with Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#client-server-communication), but wonder if there is also a way with Webpack.

Comment: I don't think so. If you find how to do it I'd like to know. The only workaround that comes to my mind is switching from `webpack-dev-server` to `webpack-dev-middleware` which would let you add your own express middleware.